# Cakephp Create Folder Upload image

Tags: php, image, upload, cakephp-2.0, directory

i want to create automatically a folder based on my idEvenememt et upload many images in this folder
my ImageevenementsController

```
    public function add($id) {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Imageevenement->create();
      $this->request->data['Imageevenement']['idEvenement'] = $id;


      $data=$this->request->data;
       $dir = IMAGES.$id;
      if(!file_exists($dir))
        mkdir($dir,0777);

       $f = explode('.',$data['Imageevenement']['file']['name']);
    $ext = '.'.end($f);
    $filename = Inflector::slug(implode('.',array_slice($f,0,-1)),'-');
    //sauvgarder eb bdd
    $success = $this->Imageevenement->save(array(
    'name' => $data['Imageevenement']['name'],
    'url' => DS.$id.'/'.$filename.$ext
    ));
   if($success){

  move_uploaded_file($data['Imageevenement']['file']  ['tmp_name'],$dir.DS.$filename.$ext);

       }else{ 
   $this ->Session->setFlash("L'image n'est pas en bonne format");}     
    }
  if ($this->Imageevenement->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The image has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index' ,   'controller'=>'evenements'));
        } 
       }
```

in my View

```
     <?php if (!empty($evenement['Imageevenement'])): ?>
              <table class="table table-bordered" >
                <tr><th> Nom</th>
                <th> Image</th>

                <th> Actions</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($evenement['Imageevenement']as $imageevenement): ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo $imageevenement['name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $imageevenement['url']; ?></td>

                    <td class="actions">
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', 'controller'=>'imageevenements', $imageevenement['idImageEvenement'])); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', 'controller'=>'imageevenements',$imageevenement['idImageEvenement'])); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete','controller'=>'imageevenements', $imageevenement['idImageEvenement']), array('confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $imageevenement['idImageEvenement']))); ?>
    </td>
                </tr>
```

the folder is created with a path begin with \ such as \1/paris.png in the data base the images are created in the folder but i can't show them . so how can i remove this \ ? why it show me nothing in the view  ? what should i do to create the folder and upload imanges in it and show them in the view ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand plz try this. I have created separate function for create a folder, for change file name, for move upload file etc. Please check if have any issue then plz let me know.

```
public function _create_folder($path) {
    $folderPath = $path ;
    if (!file_exists($folderPath.DS)) {
        App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
        $dir = new Folder($folderPath , true, 0777);
    }
    return $folderPath. DS;
}

public function moveUploadedFile($filename , $destination) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function change_file_name($fileName= null) {

    $exFileName     = strtolower(substr($fileName,strrpos($fileName,".") + 1));
    $sampleFileName = str_replace('.'.$exFileName,'', $fileName);
    $name           = Sanitize::paranoid($sampleFileName,array('_'));
    $fileRename     = $name.'.'.$exFileName;
    return $fileRename;
}


function add(){

    $file                           =     $data['Imageevenement']['file'];
    $file_name                      =     $file['name'];
    $tmp_name                       =     $file['tmp_name'];
    $return_file_name               =     $this->change_file_name($file_name);
    $path                           =     $this->_create_folder(IMAGES.DS.$id.DS);
    $return_file_name               =     $id.'/'.$return_file_name;
    if($this->moveUploadedFile($tmp_name, IMAGES.DS.$id.DS.$return_file_name)){
        $saveData['resume']         =   $return_file_name;
    }

    $success = $this->Imageevenement->save(array(
        'name' => $return_file_name,
        'url' => '/'.$id.'/'.$return_file_name
    ));

}
```

For view the image file in view.ctp

```
$imageName = $imageevenement['url'];
echo $this->Html->image(IMAGES.$imageName);
```